# How to deploy Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions for Firebase with different code base?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Firebase: Database (to store my data) and Hosting (to run my web application). The web application is build with Webpack/Vue.
Now I would like to use some Database Functions as a backend API for some server handling.

Is this possible? If so, how can I deploy two separate projects to Firebase Hosting and Functions?

Comment: Do you need them to be in separate repos? If so that's fine, you can just run `firebase deploy --only hosting` from the project dir with your hosting and `firebase deploy --only functions` from the project dir with your functions.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Have you tried something and are having a problem with your solution?

Comment: @Michael Bleigh, thank you for your comment. This makes a lote of sense. As I understand it now: I can make two projects and deploy them with the --only flag.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, there are several Firebase components like Functions, Hosting and Database. I don't run in problems jet, but I don't think I understood it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you're looking for but you can either

1. firebase deploy --only hosting or database or functions
2. or install firebase in different